# Toggle Class on Click in Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-ui-router

I have used code almost the same as this so that when I click on a certain link in my nav, it is highlighted:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p [class.active]="isParaActive">This is a paragraph tag text</p>
      <button [class.active]="isBtnActive" (click)="toggleClass()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
  `
  p{
    color: red;
  }
  p.active{
    color: green;
  }
  button{
    background-color: #00BCD4;
    color : #ffffff;
  }
  button.active{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }
  `
  ]
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
  isParaActive:boolean = false;
  isBtnActive:boolean = false;

  //ToggleClass function functionality
  toggleClass(){
      this.isParaActive = !this.isParaActive;
      this.isBtnActive = !this.isBtnActive;
  }
}
```

However, now I would like it so that whenever the user clicks anywhere else on the page, whether it is another link or anywhere else, then the link is no longer highlighted and it's class isn't active. 
Does anyone know how I can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Set a property which keeps the active element id and reset it when the outside click is produced. You would need a directive to check these clicks.

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:0" (clickOutside)="active = -1">

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor = "let person of persons; let i = index; let even = even" (click)="active = i" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': active === i ? 'red' : even ? 'yellow' : 'blue'}">
        {{person.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Component class:**

```
active = -1;
```

**Directive:**

```
Directive
import { Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

    @Output()
    clickOutside = new EventEmitter<Event>();

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyl5k4?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create a component for the navigation bar because I like to keep the `app` component as clean as possible.

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to remove the class whenever anything but the the navigation bar is clicked.

If you were to encapsulate this functionality in a component you could do the following in your `navigation` component.

```
constructor(el: ElementRef) { }



@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) docClick( event: MouseEvent ) {
    if( !this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target) ) {
       // Clicked outside   
    }
}
```